# How to logout in laravel Multi Auth using JWT

Tags: php, restful-authentication, laravel-5.5, jwt

I need help with this. i successfully set up multi auth in laravel using JWT-Auth

In login functions I put this links And its work perfect.

```
Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Models\User');
Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Models\User::class);
```

But in Logout function i put same line but its not working for logout function. its saying not found User model.
*here is the logout function.*

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['token' => 'required']);
    try {
        //Set Multi Auth Configs
        Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Models\User');
        Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Models\User::class);

        JWTAuth::invalidate($request->input('token'));
        return $this->sendResponse('','successfully logged out');
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return $this->sendError('Failed to logout, please try again.', '', 500);
    }
}
```

is there any way i can fix this issue?. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function logout(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, ['token' => 'required']);
        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate($request->input('token'));
            return response()->json(['success' => true]);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Failed to logout, please try again.'], 500);
        }
    }
```